# Null value in column of relation violates not-null constraint .net EF

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have this code:

```
foreach (ContactImportRequest row in toImport)
{
    Contact contact = _mapper.Map<Contact>(row);
        
    // if first or last names are null, we fill them with anything because are required fields
    if (contact.FirstName == null || contact.FirstName.Equals("") || contact.FirstName == String.Empty)
        contact.FirstName = "FirstName";

    if (contact.LastName == null || contact.LastName.Equals("") || contact.LastName == String.Empty)
        contact.LastName = "LastName";

    contacts.Add(contact);
}

await _context.Contacts.AddRangeAsync(contacts);
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

The `SaveChangesAsync` call breaks with the following error:

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while saving the entity changes. See the inner exception for details.
>
> Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 23502: null value in column "FirstName" of relation "Users" violates not-null constraint

I've debugged and there's no contact with `FirstName` with null value, and just in case I've added those two 'if' checking if First or Last names are null, setting a fixed value in those cases.

Also, when debugging, there's no contact in the `contacts` list with `FirstName` in null.

**UPDATE:**

The Contacts table has nothing to do with the Users table. they are two separated entities and have different properties.

Here's the Contact class:

```
public class Contact
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    
    public string? MainPhone { get; set; }
    public string? CellPhone { get; set; }
    public string? MainEmail { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("LinkedUser")]
    public string? LinkedUserId { get; set; }
    public virtual User? LinkedUser { get; set; }
}
```

**UPDATE #2:**

here's the previous lines and entire `foreach` code:

```
List<User> users = await _context.Users.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();

foreach (ContactImportRequest row in toImport)
{
    Contact contact = _mapper.Map<Contact>(row);

    contact.LinkedUserId = users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.LastName == row.LinkedUserLastName)?.Id;

    //if first or last names are null, we fill them with anything because are required fields
    if (contact.FirstName == null || contact.FirstName.Equals("") || contact.FirstName == String.Empty)
        contact.FirstName = "FirstName";
    if (contact.LastName == null || contact.LastName.Equals("") || contact.LastName == String.Empty)
        contact.LastName = "LastName";

    contacts.Add(contact);
}

await _context.Contacts.AddRangeAsync(contacts);
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

The only place I deal with Users is to get a list of them, and I'm doing it AsNoTracking.

Comment: Is Contact derived from User? Or do you have anyway to add a user automatically along with the contact where in you have forgotten to copy FirstName/LastName from contact to user?

Comment: can u provide the Model structure for the Contact and Users

Comment: You didn't post either the `User` or the `Contact` class. The error seems to complain about `User.FirstName` accessed through `Contact.Users`. BTW you can use `String.IsNullOrWhitespace()` to check whether a string is null, whitespace or empty

Comment: The error complains about `relation "Users"`. Since you attach objects directly to `Contacts` one has to assume that `Contact` has a relation `Users`. The error says there's a `null value in column "FirstName" of relation "Users"`, not in Contacts

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I've just updated the question with the Contact class from which the table has been built through EF.

Comment: EF deals with entities/classes, not tables. The error complains about `Users`. Where is the `User` class and how is it related with the code you posted? Post code that actually reproduces the error

Comment: Are you using the "repository" antipattern, with a long lived DbContext that may still track entities from a previous operation? A DbContext isn't a database connection, it's a Unit-of-Work that detects changes to all the objects it tracks for as long as it's active. It's *meant* to be short-lived and disposed when the "unit of work" terminates

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yes you're right, sorry, my eyes were seeing 'Contacts' instead of 'Users' in the error message. I've updated the question with the entire block of code so you can review it.

Comment: Finally it's getting a bit more clear. The hypothesis now is that `_context.Contacts.AddRangeAsync(contacts)` also adds new `User` objects that are void of any info, just because `_mapper.Map<Contact>(row)` creates `contact` object with empty Users. As you see, there's a *lot* of details involved before others can even begin analyzing the problem.

Comment: @GertArnold thank you! that was it, EF was trying to create a users because of the 'LinkedUser' property of contact. It was solved by setting that property on null before adding the contact into the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Auto answering my question with the solution.

The problem was that Entity Framework was considering the `LinkedUser` value as a new User to be created at the moment of Saving changes in the context.

This is the final code block working:

```
List<User> users = await _context.Users.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();

foreach (ContactImportRequest row in toImport)
{
    Contact contact = _mapper.Map<Contact>(row);

    contact.LinkedUserId = users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.LastName == row.LinkedUserLastName)?.Id;

    ///this new line solved the problem
    contact.LinkedUser = null;

    if (contact.FirstName == null || contact.FirstName.Equals("") || contact.FirstName == String.Empty)
        contact.FirstName = "FirstName";
    if (contact.LastName == null || contact.LastName.Equals("") || contact.LastName == String.Empty)
        contact.LastName = "LastName";

    contacts.Add(contact);
}

await _context.Contacts.AddRangeAsync(contacts);
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Thanks to a few users that commented on the original question and lead me to the solution.

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, you can replace a lot of the checking with:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(contact.FirstName)) 
{
    contact.FirstName = "FirstName";
}
```

Secondly, the error appears to be with the `Users` relationship, not the `Contacts` table.  I'm assuming that your `Contacts` table is not called `Users` in the database, but you might want to check the relationships instead of this specific function.

Comment: This is basically two comments, not an answer. Also, the second comment is based on an incorrect assumption. It's about the *relation* "Users", i.e. in relational database terms: the table. Not a *relationship*. As usual, it's better to withhold answers until the question is clear enough (in this case: at least shows the `Contact` class an its mapping).

Comment: @GertArnold is right, the Contacts and Users table are different things in my project, I don't think I've said something about they being the same.

Comment: @ajzbrun you implied they are when you only posted code about `Contact` and asked what's going on with it, not Users. Don't force people to guess, post the Contact and User *objects*, along with the code that fills `Contact.Users`. Something's wrong there

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I didn't implied that Users had something to do with Contacts, please review carefully the question. I've just updated with Contact class.